# How do you change the color of all of the nodes of a specific name in SpriteKit with Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to change the color of every single instance of a node in SpriteKit. When I try to put it in the update method, it only changes one and not all of them.

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    if changeColor {
        self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("blocks", usingBlock: { node, stop in
            block?.color = UIColor.orangeColor()
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should change the color of the `node`, not of some `block` variable. You will retrieve all `SKNode`s with that name. But those nodes don't have a color property. Only some subclasses, for example the `SKSpriteNode` have a `color` property. You therefore have to add some additional logic to change the color. For example you could try to convert the `node` to `SKSpriteNode` and only then change the `color`:

```
self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("blocks", usingBlock: { node, stop in
    if let sprite = node as? SKSpriteNode {
        sprite.color = UIColor.orangeColor()
    }
})
```

As @appzYourLife correctly mentioned that code can be simplified / swiftyfied to

```
self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("blocks") { node, stop in
    if let sprite = node as? SKSpriteNode {
        sprite.color = .orangeColor()
    }
}
```

Comment: Still too fast for me! I just needed one more minute to complete my own answer :D

Comment: Just a couple of very tiny refinements. **1)** In the color assignment you can omit the `UIColor` part `sprite.color = .orangeColor()`. **2)** You can also use the trailing closure syntax to remove a few more words from the code.

Comment: @appzYourLife thank you for that remark, I included it.